# Logi Analytics (Info) generating reports mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Logi Analytics and wanted to generate reports using mongoDB as backend. I have tried using 'Big Data Layers' in Logi Analytics like MongoFind and MongoRunCommand but could not configure them correctly. Can someone help me with this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use datalayers in Logi Info you'll need to first configure a data source connections in the settings file of your app. Then on the MongoFind and MongoRunCommand datalayers there will be a "connection id" attribute. Set this to reference the data source connection that you configured and you should be good to go.

Documentation here: http://devnet.logianalytics.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=2101&dnProd=2